# PHP - Smartly increase memory limit based on server hardware capabilities

Tags: php, memory, memory-limit

Is there some way to intelligently increase the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` based on the capabilities of the server hardware?

For example, I have a server with 16 GB of Ram, whose only function is to run a web platform. I want to increase the `memory_limit` but I don't want to look like a fool uploading memory with a random number. Or for a web platform where the processes are not so high, you should put `-1` to have no memory limit?

Comment: Why don't you leave the defaults and increase the limit when it comes to any problem?

Comment: sure it can be scripted, maybe one line of bash, `free -m | grep -oP '\d+' | head -n 1 | awk '{$1=$1/(1024); print int($1)"G";}'` why would it be random? what are you *uploading*? do you have 100's of servers to deploy? or just one?

Comment: It is only a server, I said random number, but what I meant is that I don't want to be changing the number as each time that error appears on the server.